# Use 2 RTC Alarm on STM32L073RZ

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, low-power, rtc, nucleo

I'm trying to configure two different alarms on my STM32L073RZ with the given example by StMicroelectronics.
The problem is, when I try something like the script below, only the first Alarm turned on work (in this case Alarm B).
This Alarms help me to leave the deepSleep mode of my STM32. Maybe the problem come from the configuration of my deepSleep mode ? Some informations can be lost when the device wake up ?

```
  /*##-3- Configure the RTC Alarm peripheral #################################*/
  /* Set Alarm to 02:21:20*/
  salarmstructure.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x21;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x20;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;
  if(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&RTCHandle,&salarmstructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    // Initialization Error
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* Set Alarm to 02:20:30*/
  salarmstructure.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_B;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY ;
  salarmstructure.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x20;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x30;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;
  if(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&RTCHandle,&salarmstructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

EDIT: After some tests the problem come from my RTC Time. After the wakeUp to leave the DeepSleep my RTC Time go to 00:00:00

If you need more informations this is my complete script with the configuration of deepSleep mode and the configuration of the two Alarms.

```
#include "main.h"

/** @addtogroup STM32L0xx_HAL_Examples
  * @{
  */

/** @addtogroup PWR_STANDBY_RTC
  * @{
  */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* RTC handler declaration */
RTC_HandleTypeDef RTCHandle;


/* Buffer used for displaying Time */
uint8_t aShowTime[50] = {0};
static __IO uint32_t TimingDelay;

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void SystemPower_Config(void);
static void Error_Handler(void);
static void RTC_AlarmConfig(void);
static void RTC_TimeShow(uint8_t* showtime);
int etatFlag = 0;

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
  * @brief  Main program
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* STM32L0xx HAL library initialization:
       - Configure the Flash prefetch, Flash preread and Buffer caches
       - Systick timer is configured by default as source of time base, but user 
             can eventually implement his proper time base source (a general purpose 
             timer for example or other time source), keeping in mind that Time base 
             duration should be kept 1ms since PPP_TIMEOUT_VALUEs are defined and 
             handled in milliseconds basis.
       - Low Level Initialization
     */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock to 2 MHz */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Configure LED2 */
  BSP_LED_Init(LED2);

  RTCHandle.Instance = RTC;

  /* Configure RTC prescaler and RTC data registers */
  /* RTC configured as follows:
      - Hour Format    = Format 24
      - Asynch Prediv  = Value according to source clock
      - Synch Prediv   = Value according to source clock
      - OutPut         = Output Disable
      - OutPutPolarity = High Polarity
      - OutPutType     = Open Drain */
  RTCHandle.Init.HourFormat     = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  RTCHandle.Init.AsynchPrediv   = RTC_ASYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.SynchPrediv    = RTC_SYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPut         = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutType     = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&RTCHandle) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-2- Configure Alarm ####################################################*/
  /* Configure RTC Alarm */
  //RTC_AlarmConfig();

  /* Configure the system Power */
  //SystemPower_Config();
  /* Check and handle if the system was resumed from StandBy mode */ 
  if(__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB) != RESET)
  {
    /* Clear Standby flag */
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB);
    //etatFlag = 1;
  }
  //Simon NOWAK
  //Branch to verify if this is the first loop for the STM32
  //The PWR_FLAG_WU change after a wakeUp or after the interruption of AlarmB
  if(__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU) != SET)
  {
      RTC_AlarmConfig();
  }

  /* Configure the system Power */
  SystemPower_Config();

  /* Insert 5 seconds delay */
  HAL_Delay(5000);

  /* The Following Wakeup sequence is highly recommended prior to each Standby mode entry
    mainly  when using more than one wakeup source this is to not miss any wakeup event.
    - Disable all used wakeup sources,
    - Clear all related wakeup flags, 
    - Re-enable all used wakeup sources,
    - Enter the Standby mode.
  */
  /* Disable all used wakeup sources*/
  HAL_RTCEx_DeactivateWakeUpTimer(&RTCHandle);

  /* Re-enable all used wakeup sources*/
  /* ## Setting the Wake up time ############################################*/
  /*  RTC Wakeup Interrupt Generation:
    Wakeup Time Base = (RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV /(LSI))
    Wakeup Time = Wakeup Time Base * WakeUpCounter
      = (RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV /(LSI)) * WakeUpCounter
      ==> WakeUpCounter = Wakeup Time / Wakeup Time Base

    To configure the wake up timer to 4s the WakeUpCounter is set to 0x1FFF:
    RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV = RTCCLK_Div16 = 16
    Wakeup Time Base = 16 /(~39.000KHz) = ~0,410 ms
    Wakeup Time = ~4s = 0,410ms  * WakeUpCounter
      ==> WakeUpCounter = ~4s/0,410ms = 9750 = 0x2616 */



  /* Clear all related wakeup flags */
  __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);

  //Re-enable all used wakeup sources
  //
  HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&RTCHandle, 0xFFF, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_CK_SPRE_16BITS);

  /* Enter the Standby mode */
  HAL_PWR_EnterSTANDBYMode();

  while (1)
  {
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  System Clock Configuration
  *         The system Clock is configured as follow : 
  *            System Clock source            = MSI
  *            SYSCLK(Hz)                     = 2000000
  *            HCLK(Hz)                       = 2000000
  *            AHB Prescaler                  = 1
  *            APB1 Prescaler                 = 1
  *            APB2 Prescaler                 = 1
  *            Flash Latency(WS)              = 0
  *            Main regulator output voltage  = Scale3 mode
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};

  /* Enable MSI Oscillator */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_5;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue=0x00;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    while(1); 
  }

  /* Select MSI as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 
     clocks dividers */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;  
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;  
  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0)!= HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    while(1); 
  }
  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the device is 
     clocked below the maximum system frequency, to update the voltage scaling value 
     regarding system frequency refer to product datasheet.  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  /* Disable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_DISABLE();

}


/**
  * @brief  System Power Configuration
  *         The system Power is configured as follow :
  *            + RTC Clocked by LSI
  *            + VREFINT OFF, with fast wakeup enabled
  *            + No IWDG
  *            + Automatic Wakeup using RTC clocked by LSI (after ~4s)
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void SystemPower_Config(void)
{
  /* Enable Power Control clock */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_PWREx_EnableUltraLowPower();

  /* Enable the fast wake up from Ultra low power mode */
  HAL_PWREx_EnableFastWakeUp();

  /* Configure RTC */
  RTCHandle.Instance = RTC;
  /* Set the RTC time base to 1s */
  /* Configure RTC prescaler and RTC data registers as follow:
    - Hour Format = Format 24
    - Asynch Prediv = Value according to source clock
    - Synch Prediv = Value according to source clock
    - OutPut = Output Disable
    - OutPutPolarity = High Polarity
    - OutPutType = Open Drain */
  RTCHandle.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  RTCHandle.Init.AsynchPrediv = RTC_ASYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.SynchPrediv = RTC_SYNCH_PREDIV;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  RTCHandle.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if(HAL_RTC_Init(&RTCHandle) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler(); 
  }
}


/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* Turn on the LED2 */
  BSP_LED_On(LED2);
  while(1)
  {
  }
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif

/**
  * @brief  Alarm callback
  * @param  hrtc : RTC handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc)
{
  /* Turn LED2 on: Alarm generation */
  BSP_LED_On(LED2);
}

/**
  * @brief  Configure the current time and date.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void RTC_AlarmConfig(void)
{
  RTC_DateTypeDef  sdatestructure;
  RTC_TimeTypeDef  stimestructure;
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef salarmstructure;
  RTC_AlarmTypeDef salarmstructure2;


  /*##-1- Configure the Date #################################################*/
  /* Set Date: Tuesday February 18th 2014 */
  sdatestructure.Year = 0x14;
  sdatestructure.Month = RTC_MONTH_FEBRUARY;
  sdatestructure.Date = 0x18;
  sdatestructure.WeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_TUESDAY;

  if(HAL_RTC_SetDate(&RTCHandle,&sdatestructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    BSP_LED_On(LED2);
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-2- Configure the Time #################################################*/
  /* Set Time: 02:20:00 */
  stimestructure.Hours = 0x02;
  stimestructure.Minutes = 0x20;
  stimestructure.Seconds = 0x00;
  stimestructure.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  stimestructure.DayLightSaving = RTC_DAYLIGHTSAVING_NONE ;
  stimestructure.StoreOperation = RTC_STOREOPERATION_RESET;

  if(HAL_RTC_SetTime(&RTCHandle,&stimestructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    BSP_LED_On(LED2);
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-3- Configure the RTC Alarm peripheral #################################*/
  /* Set Alarm to 02:21:20*/
  salarmstructure.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_A;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x21;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x20;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;
  if(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&RTCHandle,&salarmstructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    // Initialization Error
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* Set Alarm to 02:20:30*/
  salarmstructure.Alarm = RTC_ALARM_B;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDay = RTC_WEEKDAY_MONDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmDateWeekDaySel = RTC_ALARMDATEWEEKDAYSEL_WEEKDAY;
  salarmstructure.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY ;
  salarmstructure.AlarmSubSecondMask = RTC_ALARMSUBSECONDMASK_NONE;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.TimeFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT12_AM;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Hours = 0x02;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Minutes = 0x20;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.Seconds = 0x30;
  salarmstructure.AlarmTime.SubSeconds = 0x56;
  if(HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&RTCHandle,&salarmstructure,RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief  Display the current time.
  * @param  showtime : pointer to buffer
  * @retval None
  */
static void RTC_TimeShow(uint8_t* showtime)
{
  RTC_DateTypeDef sdatestructureget;
  RTC_TimeTypeDef stimestructureget;

  /* Get the RTC current Time */
  HAL_RTC_GetTime(&RTCHandle, &stimestructureget, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
  /* Get the RTC current Date */
  HAL_RTC_GetDate(&RTCHandle, &sdatestructureget, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
  /* Display time Format : hh:mm:ss */
  sprintf((char*)showtime,"%02d:%02d:%02d",stimestructureget.Hours, stimestructureget.Minutes, stimestructureget.Seconds);
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
#endif
```

Thank you for your attention and for your help.

Comment: You can answer your own question with the solution... That will help someone in future

Comment: I didn't have any solution for the moment, just a lot of problems.

Comment: You edit "After some tests the problem come from my RTC Time. After the wakeUp to leave the DeepSleep my RTC Time go to 00:00:00" sounded like that was the problem

Comment: Yes, this is the problem but I don't know how to solve it.